# Android SQliteOpenHelper delete statement issue

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Trying to refresh a catalog items table .. just a basic database operation I'm stuck with a strange behaviour

```
String purgeItems ="DELETE FROM CatalogItems";

String count = "SELECT * FROM CatalogItems";

SQLiteDatabase db = mDb.getWritableDatabase(); // mDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper

db.beginTransaction();
db.rawQuery(purgeItems,null);
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(count, null);
Log.e(TAG, "CatalogItems after purge " + String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
```

**returns 642 : the original table rows count**

... ! perhaps I'm tired ^^. it does work fine with other tables ..

the SQLiteOpenHelper (mDb) creation table code

```
private void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // --- CATALOG ITEMS ---
    String catalogItemsTable = "CREATE TABLE CatalogItems (" +
            "idCatalogItem      INT(11) PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "idCatalog  INT(11), " +
            "idProduct  INT(11), " +
            "image     BLOB, " +
            "price     FLOAT, " +
            "quantity     INT(11), " +
            "unit     VARCHAR(5), " +
            "status  INT(11), " +
            "extras   VARCHAR(512) " +
            ");" ;

db.execSQL(catalogItemsTable);
Log.i(TAG, "table CatalogItems created");
```

Comment: probably you need to put some conditions. DELETE FROM CatalogItems where blabla = 'abc'

Comment: replace `db.rawQuery(purgeItems,null);` with `db.execSQL(purgeItems,null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawQuery` is meant for queries that return rows. Instead use:

```
db.execSQL(purgeItems);
```

Comment: Shame on me !!! .. I'am French and just java "beginner" .. just thought that rawQuery was a real basic method to interpret SQL statements .. Thans a lot ! ^^